# Total variance of a function of independent random variables

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, random-variables, variance

Take a function of two random variables $Z = m(X,Y)$. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, it should be possible to express the variance of $Z$ in terms of functional transforms of individual random variables, for instance like:
$$
{\rm Var}(Z) = {\rm Var}(m(X,Y)) = m_0({\rm Var}(X),{\rm Var}(Y)) + {\rm Var}(m_1(X)) + {\rm Var}(m_2(Y))
$$
If so, what would be the functional of $m_0$, $m_1$ and $m_2$?

Comment: Of course not in general, try $m(x,y)=xy$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I revised my question to add a third functional. Then it should be possible to match a general case.

Comment: Apparently the message that your quest is hopeless did not carry through. Second try (and after that, you are on your own, sorry): try $m(x,y)=1/(1+x^2y^2)$.